# Basic Nmos amplifier working

Tags: amplifier, nmos

I am trying to understand this circuit here.[image]

I do not understand clearly how this works. I know that the PMOS is a current source but what impact does the resistor Rb have on this ?  Could anyone help me out with its working ?

Comment: Before this question can be answered, you need to explain what you DO understand. Also, what is your overall level of education and experience in electronics?

Comment: Sorry my bad, will edit and rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rb is biasing the NMOS into saturation (a good thing).

Rb is **also** a bootstrap Resistor (maybe good, likely not). Based on the size of Rb, this can do a few things. It can make the NMOS, look like:

- A capacitive input
- A pure resistive input (nice, but not practical due to tolerances)
- An inductive input

It could also turn the circuit into an oscillator by destroying the phase margin. Bootstrapping is a fun thing.

Comment: Even if Rb was not there it would be a normal diode connected transistor. This would also ensure biasing. And for this case is Vds = Vgs, too?? And what does a bootstrap resistor do ??

Comment: And it also says in my notes that Rb self biases the circuit, but I am finding this hard to understand.

Comment: @BhuvaneshN, If Rb was not there, then there's no telling what would happen. If there were no charges on the gate, then it would be off. If there were some, then it could be in linear or saturation. However, since Rb is there, after a few time constants (Rb*Nmos_gate_capacitance) the Nmos would be in saturation and very little DC current would feed through Rb. **If Rb is sufficiently large, then very little signal will pass through it instead of into the gate of the mosfet for amplification**. That's why it's not a wire. But, the larger Rb is then the longer it takes to get the NMOS into sat.

Comment: This circuit still haunts me..Sure I get  that a big Rb allows more signal to the gate, What if Rb is disconnected or open circuited ? Then the gate is going to get the entire signal.. But by doing this we completely remove the feedback that we get from the output. But my question is how does his feedback actually work ? There exists a drain voltage at M1 and there is also this gate voltage at M1, but how do these 2 thing work together to provide a better amplification ?

Comment: That's a mosfet device characteristic question. Basically, mosfets have the highest trans-conductance in saturation, and Saturation is when Vgs>Vth and Vgs>=Vds. Rb forces a saturation condition on M1. In my answer, I said that was good. Without Rb, M1 is floating and unpredictable. Unpredictable makes for a bad amplifier.